# Handling a TypeError in a for loop, when calling push function

Tags: javascript, json, typeerror

I'm working on a webdata connector and currently struggling with handling an error. The WDC is written in Javascript.
Now to my issue. Let's say an API returns the following JSON payload:

```
[
  {
    "type": "foo",
    "licensePlate": "bar",
    "mainEngine": null
  },
  {
    "type": "foo",
    "licensePlate": "bar",
    "mainEngine": {
      "fuelType" "fooBar"
    }
  }
]
```

The data from the API is pushed into a table with a for loop. In the following the exemplary loop:

```
// some code
for (var i = 0, len = jsonData.length; i < len; i++) {
  tableData.push({
    "type": jsonData[i].type,
    "licensePlate": jsonData[i].licensePlate,
    "fuelType": jsonData[i].mainEngine.fuelType
  });
}
// some code
```

The type error arises because jsonData[i].mainEngine is null. I thought about wrapping the for-loop in a try and catch block, see:

```
// some code
for (var i = 0, len = jsonData.length; i < len; i++) {
  try {
    tableData.push({
      "type": jsonData[i].type,
      "licensePlate": jsonData[i].licensePlate,
      "fuelType": jsonData[i].mainEngine.fuelType
  });
  } catch (e) {
      console.log("An error occurred")
    }

}
// some code
```

The for loop will now execute completely, but the data is not completely pushed into the table. I could observe for some entries that whenever the fuelType property is null in the table, properties like licensePlate are not correctly populated, meaning they're missing completely.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, len = jsonData.length; i < len; i++) {
  tableData.push({
    "type": jsonData[i].type,
    "licensePlate": jsonData[i].licensePlate,
    "fuelType": jsonData[i].mainEngine && jsonData[i].mainEngine.fuelType
  });
}
```